# Redux persist does not store Any Data for Offline Use

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

> I am using redux, redux-persist with middleware redux-thunk to
>   fetch Json 
>       API..
>       My Problem is i cannot use it anymore when wifi is off..
>       Storage Does'nt work well to use offline.

```
 Here is my codes.

 Store.js 
 -------------
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './RootReducers';

const middleware = [thunk];
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const enhancers = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
);

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, enhancers)
    const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor: persistor };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to call your exported function from `configureStore.js`.

Call it inside your app entrypoint.
I think at this point, the **redux-persist** lib is poorly documented, because you can find the most solutions inside the issue tab.

**This works for me:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

// store
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import configureStore from './configureStore.js';

// call your store config
const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <div>
             App
          </div>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```